# Some questions on shape creation

Tags: android, shapes, android-xml

I am digging into shapes and found some questions which were hard to find an answer. Hope you can help me:

1 - What is the meaning of shape="0" ?

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="0"
>
```

2 - Why setting so precise value of corners? Is there some tool maybe that converts shapes into XML and that's the reason for such precision?

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="0"
    >
    <gradient
    ...
    >
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="0.100000024dip"
        android:topRightRadius="0.100000024dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10.0dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10.0dip"
        >
    </corners>
</shape>
```

3 - What is the best radius for background gradient? I saw some people use 300-and-something value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less complete info on shapes is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#shape-element)

1. I suppose 0 means default value("rectangle")
2. There's no need in such precision. You can even use non-float values(10dip equals 10.0dip)
3. "The best value" always depends on the task. Try and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting that sample code?  It looks crazy!  [Here is the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) on ShapeDrawables.  The `android:shape` tells Android what kind of shape it is.  The choices are "rectangle", "oval", "line" and "ring".  The corner radius is in what ever units you specify.  In the example you show it's in Density Independent Pixels which means it should look the same on all devices, but still, 0.100000024 pixels doesn't make much sense anywhere!  The radius of the gradient depends on what look you're going for.  If you want it to fill the screen, or overflow the edge or just be in one corner.

Comment: I took the code from the app my colleague got from the big Android developing company. They are really huge and I doubt they used it with no reason. I do not know.

Comment: You'd be surprised how bad code can be even when written by "professional" developers!